# Does "dap" delete everything?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I'm familiar with the "dd" and "d{motion}" commands, but can't find "dap" in vim's help.txt. What does "dap" do in normal mode and why? (Alternatively, how can I find out this sort of thing for myself?)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

"dap" does not actually delete everything. For example, try putting this into your buffer:

```
1
1

2
2

3
3
```

Then put your cursor on either '2' and type "dap". It'll leave the '1's and '3's.

This is because "dap" deletes a *paragraph*. In fact, that's actually the mnemonic: "(D)elete (A) (P)aragraph". You can see it in the help under `:h ap`:

```
                            *v_ap* *ap*
ap          "a paragraph", select [count] paragraphs (see
            |paragraph|).
            Exception: a blank line (only containing white space)
            is also a paragraph boundary.
            When used in Visual mode it is made linewise.
```

This is called a "text object". You can read about these under: [`:h text-objects`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#text-objects), or you can read [this awesome article on text objects.](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/10/17/vim-text-objects-the-definitive-guide/)

Either way, the basic idea of text-objects is that you are defining the boundaries of an *object* and then apply commands to that whole object even when you're in the middle of it. For example, I'm sure you know you can use `dw` to delete a word. But what if you're in this scenario?

```
Hello world
Cursor: ^
```

If you type `dw`, you'll still have the `wo` left. If you type `diw`, that will delete *inside of the word*, so for the most part it's equivalent to typing `bdw`.

> How can I find out this sort of thing for myself?

You had the basic idea down! Checking the help is always a good start. In this case, you could have realized that `d` is an operator, so the help you were really looking for was the argument to the operator, in this case `ap`.

Comment: +1! To be pedantic: diw leaves the trailing space, while bdw does not. diw would be the same as bde ;-) The pendant for bdw is actually daw, which uses the same "a" as the stroke in the question.

Comment: @M.Herzkamp: And yet `diw` and `bde` are still not quite the same: if your cursor's on the beginning of a word. Likewise, if your cursor is on a space between words, then `bdw` will delete the word on the left, while `daw` will delete the word on the right. I think the original answer's "for the most part…" is probably the best that we'll get in terms of these equivalences.